# SyntaxError: JSON.parse: Unexpected characters

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

I am trying to display the response of a call from the skyscanner API with this code:

```
  function ajaxGet(url, callback) {

      var req = new XMLHttpRequest();

      req.open("GET", url);

      req.addEventListener("load", function () {

          if (req.status >= 200 && req.status < 400) {

              callback(req.responseText);
          } else {
              console.error(req.status + " " + req.statusText + " " + url);
          }
      });

      req.addEventListener("error", function () {
          console.error("Erreur réseau avec l'URL " + url);
      });
      req.send(null);
  }


  ajaxGet("http://partners.api.skyscanner.net/apiservices/browseroutes/v1.0/GB/GBP/en-GB/US/anywhere/anytime/anytime?apiKey=mo432604......1342", function (response) {

      var elements = JSON.parse(response)

      elements.forEach(function (ele) {

          console.log(ele);
      })
  });
```

But I get this error in the Firefox console:

> SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

I checked if the API call was valid with Curl:

```
curl http://partners.api.skyscanner.net/apiservices/browseroutes/v1.0/GB/GBP/en-GB/US/anywhere/anytime/anytime?apiKey=mo432604...1342
```

And it's valid as I get a response like this:

```
{"Routes":[{"OriginId":1811,"DestinationId":943,"QuoteIds":[1,2],"Price":148.0,"QuoteDateTime":"2017-04-10T02:00:00"},
```

So, I don't see where I am wrong in my code. Any help ?

Thanks

Comment: Is the header Content-Type that gets passed back from the URL set to `Content-Type: application/json`?

Comment: Check what the actual request returned in the browser's dev tools (network tab)

Comment: @aug Ok thanks I added the header "Content-Type" to my request and the error is gone, but I have a new one now, 405 Method Not allowed, because it seems that the call was sent with the OPTION method...

Comment: That's most certainly a CORS request. Does the API support it? Maybe it's meant to be queried from a server only?

Comment: Ok, I think I will need to open another Post for this but whatever, I found a page where skyscanner staff suggest two solutions when one want to make Ajax calls over HTTPs (which is my case), one is to use Curl and make a bridge from Curl to my app the other is to use a Web Server Proxy, but they don't give more explanation, what is the meaning of using a proxy ?